# "Age: 0" HTTP Header

Tags: http, http-headers

What is the HTTP header "Age" for?  Specifically, what does a value of 0 (`Age: "0"`) mean?

Comment: So, it's a girl or a boy?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See the [HTTP 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) on what the [*Age* header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.6) is intended to be used for:

> The Age response-header field conveys the sender's estimate of the amount of time since the response (or its revalidation) was generated at the origin server.

This information is used by intermediate proxies to [convey an estimate of how old a stored response is](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.3):

> HTTP/1.1 requires origin servers to send a Date header, if possible, with every response, giving the time at which the response was generated (see section 14.18). We use the term "date_value" to denote the value of the Date header, in a form appropriate for arithmetic operations.
>
> HTTP/1.1 uses the Age response-header to convey the estimated age of the response message when obtained from a cache. The Age field value is the cache's estimate of the amount of time since the response was generated or revalidated by the origin server.

Furthermore, the *Age* header field is intended to be used by intermediate caches only:

> The presence of an Age header field in a response implies that a response is not first-hand.

That means the presence of the header field `Age: 0` means that the received response was sent by an intermediate cache and is only zero seconds old. So it was probably just fetched from the origin server before sending it to the client.

Comment: you are implying that this "cache" is another proxy server or should be another proxy server and if it's the origin server that is responding directly, the age response header should not be set. I dont see that in the standard, it could be an origin server cache no?

Comment: @Blub The cache can be any node between the client and server. There may be multiple proxies on the route or none at all. The cache would set the *Age* header field value according to the age of the stored representation of the requested resource.

Answer (score 5):

"The Age header indicates an estimation, in number of seconds, of the age of the resource being requested since it was last requested from the Web server of origin."

"Because network delays can result in improperly low ages being calculated, the age is recalculated at each step in the return path based on the estimated time between hops.  Rather than depending on the calculations made by other intermediate proxies, the age will usually be calculated as a difference between the proxy's current date and the Date general header included in the HTTP response.  **If unsynchronized clocks make this calculation resulting in a negative difference, an age of 0 is used.**"

Chris Shiflett, "HTTP Developer's Handbook," page 83.

Answer (score 3):

That happens to be specified [in the protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

> The Age response-header field conveys the sender's estimate of the
>   amount of time since the response (or its revalidation) was
>   generated at the origin server. A cached response is "fresh" if
>   its age does not exceed its freshness lifetime. Age values are
>   calculated as specified in section 13.2.3.
>
> ```
>    Age = "Age" ":" age-value
>    age-value = delta-seconds
> ```
>
> Age values are non-negative decimal integers, representing time in
>   seconds.
>   If a cache receives a value larger than the largest positive
>   integer it can represent, or if any of its age calculations
>   overflows, it MUST transmit an Age header with a value of
>   2147483648 (2^31). An HTTP/1.1 server that includes a cache MUST
>   include an Age header field in every response generated from its
>   own cache. Caches SHOULD use an arithmetic type of at least 31
>   bits of range.